# What CSS element controls bootstrap's scrollspy's active/hover?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

http://examine.com/v5x/creatine.html#summary - hover over Summary.

What's the CSS that controls it? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: you might want to put some actual code in your post, no-one can access a file on your desktop!

Comment: Wow I am a dunce :(. Copy pasted the wrong URL sheesh me. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Active: `active` class (true for most Bootstrap features)

Hover:

```
.navbar .nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar .nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

[Source](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy)

**EDIT**

Line 3804 of your CSS:

```
.nav-list > .active > a,
.nav-list > .active > a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: #0088cc;
}
```

`background-color` here is causing your blue background. Simply change it to the desired value, and change `color` to `color: #00A5B5;`.

Comment: Thanks - that does work - any way to do it without editing bootstrap.css?

I tried putting this into docs.css (which gets called after):


>    .nav-list > .active > a,
>    .nav-list > .active > a:hover {
>      text-shadow: none;
>      background-color: none;
>     }

But that did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sure, just put the modified part of the CSS into a separate file/in your document header and add !important, e.g. `.nav-list > .active > a, .nav-list > .active > a:hover { color: #00A5B5 !important; background-color: transparent !important; }` - and make sure it's declared **after** including bootstrap.css.

Answer (score 0):

the solution goes like this:

edit *docs.css*, comment out

```
  background:none; //line 728 under .bs-docs-sidenav > .active > a {
```

and edit *bootstrap.css*, comment out

```
  background-color: #0088cc;//line 3807 under .nav-list > .active > a:hover {
```

and change

```
color: #ffffff;//line 3805 under .nav-list > .active > a:hover {
```

to

```
  color: #00A5B5;
```

and don't forget to clear your browsers' cache before checking the changes..

Comment: It's based on scrollspy. The highlighting is from it, not on me setting the class.

When I put .active {background-color:pink;}, that blue highlight still happened on the active/hover state.

Comment: yes..you are right..but you want to remove that bluish background on hover..isn't it..??

Comment: Nope, that isn't it.

The active class is what is changing the font color from the grey to the blue. It is some other combination of active AND hover that is adding that link-color background.

And I cannot figure out what that bloody class/CSS is :(

Comment: have you commented out the above blocks of code from `bootstrap-scrollspy.js`..??

Comment: Yep. the class="active" is what makes the font-color blue. It is not what causes that blue background (on hover).