# What CSS class controls the active element for bootstrap's typeahead?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What CSS element controls bootstrap’s scrollspy’s active/hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128214/what-css-element-controls-bootstraps-scrollspys-active-hover)

What CSS class(es) control the active element for bootstrap's typeahead?

I know it adds the class "active", but which class is active a subclass of?

Answer (score 0):

The `ul` created by Typeahead is assigned the class `typeahead`.

So you're probably looking for something like:
`ul.typeahead li.active`

Comment: Hrmm, that should work, but I can't seem to make it work.

I tried:
ul.typeahead li.active
.typeahead.active
.typeahead.active a

Any clue? It's the typeahead search here: http://examine.com/v5x/creatine.html

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong questions - knowing CSS classes won't help if you're not using them correctly. Post **all** of the problematic code in a new question and explain what isn't working; you'll get much more accurate/helpful answers.